# How is justification related to truth?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

We all learned to believe in true belief; some of us don’t anymore. I’ve found that better ideas are available to us if we don’t. Some ideas are better (better justified by evidence and logic) than others. I think that truth is irrelevant to justification; it's no longer the gold standard of human understanding - that distinction should be associated with coherency, which is based on [critical theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/critical-theory/) and is manifested through the application of [critical thinking](http://stearnscenter.gmu.edu/wp-content/uploads/12-The-Delphi-Report-on-Critical-Thinking.pdf) practices: analysis, justification, explanation and metacognitive self-correction.

Is the concept 'justification' related to the idea 'truth'? If so, how? That is, what's the justification to indicate that truth is somehow related (in a philosophico-linguistic theory or model) to the process of justification? If we believe in knowing the truth then justification is about determining the truth *subjectively* in practice, but if we're satisfied with understanding which are the best ideas that people have proposed about a topic, then coherency is gold and truth is dross (IMO!).

Comment: Experience. It is possible to be aware that one's hallucinations are not real (just a product of a malfunctioning mind). It is also possible to have extreme difficulty accepting a perfectly real experience for what it truly is. These attitudes might be found in people who tend to question and analyze everything. Others might accept everything at face value, without a second thought.

Comment: Since you are interested in psychology to it seems, you have to take into account the knower himself. We can't really have a generic Subject. Some subjects will know themselves and understand themselves better than others. On a more sophisticated level: Russell Jacoby, "Social Amnesia" on a more practical level with an odd but interesting "Kantian Approach" of Dooyeweerd.

Comment: @Bread *Experience*…Well, yes, subjectively that's what we do - if and only if our purpose is to discern Truth. I was inviting speculation on the abstract theoretical connection between these two linguistic constructs. I've already opined that they're unrelated in theory, and you're correct to point  out that some of us relate them subjectively in practice. I'm inquiring whether anyone can explain a coherent hypothetical connection, a theoretical model...I appreciate your participation,@B. Thanks for doing philosophy together!

Comment: You have to take into account the subject who would even attempt to "know".

Comment: @Gordon, yes, as Bread pointed out. I suggested that truthseekers and truthmongers do relate these ideas in practice, but what's the justification that such a relationship is appropriate or useful? That's what I'm asking.

Comment: Dooyeweerd pages:  http://dooy.info/#understanding

Comment: Okay. I understand better now. What truth are they after. A narrow truth?  A truth at an instant in time? Or a more contextual truth. Historical context, etc. Ultimately, as so often happens in philosophy, this is the one and many question. Now separately but importantly, as to what the subject himself may bring with him to the game: "emotional baggage" or certain presuppositions, see R. Jacoby and H. Dooyeweerd perhaps.

Comment: Or to make thinks easier perhaps stick with Rorty and those books written on pragmatism as the proper approach after Rorty.

Comment: @Gordon..."*the subject himself may bring with him to the game: "emotional baggage"*...Yes, but that's about the psychology of communicating, which is another of my interests. This topic pertains to the areas of philosophy of science and phil of language.

Comment: @Gordon.."*stick with Rorty and those books written on pragmatism*"...Well, that's an option...but it's not available if one insists on believing that certain truth is a potential attribute of *knowing* as it manifests in human beings: linguistic understandings, subjective or publicly contended (objective) discourses (speech and texts).